# dijit single dialog page control

Tags: dojo, dialog, attributes

I create a dijit.Dialog and show/hide when needed.  However now I need to track control as I am unable to undim the screen at times.  I turned all the "dialog.show/hide" into a function call which I have as below.  But is says dialog00Reg is undefined.  Why?  What is the better way to do this?

```
  function dialogState(obj,state){
    var dialog00Reg;
    require(["dijit/registry"], function(registry){
      dialog00Reg= registry.byId(obj);
       if(state=="show"){
         if(!(dialog00Reg.open)){
           dialog00Reg.show();
         }
       }
       if(state=="hide"){
         if(dialog00Reg.open){
           dialog00Reg.hide();
         }
       }
    });
  }
```

Comment: What is 'obj'? `registry.byId` is expecting a string ID. Also, why not just keep a reference to the dialog when you create it?

Comment: @jason0x43
I create the dialog in onLoad of the page."obj" is just my attempt to parametrize which right now is only "dialog" but could other dialogs.  What is the proper way to create/show/hide a single dialog from multiple uses on a single page?

Answer (score 1):

How you manage the dialog depends on how your page is structured. One way would be to do something like the following. This assumes you're controlling the dialog through event handlers.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- head tags ... -->

        <script src="somewhere/dojo.js" data-dojo-props="async:true"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- tags ... -->

        <script>
            require([
              'dojo/on',
              'dijit/Dialog',
              ...
            ], function (on, Dialog, ...) {
                var dialog;

                on(document.getElementById('showButton'), 'click', function () {
                    if (!dialog) {
                        // Create the dialog if it doesn't already exist
                        dialog = new Dialog({ ... });
                    }
                    dialog.show();
                });

                on(document.getElementById('hideButton'), 'click', function () {
                    if (dialog) {
                        dialog.hide();
                    }
                });

                ...
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this example a single script manages dialog creation and all the listeners that interact with a dialog. Since the dialog is created here, it's easy to keep a reference to it, so the listeners never have to search for it.

If your dialog is created somewhere else, and you know the ID of the dialog, you could do something your original example. However, it would be simpler to put that functionality in the handlers where it was needed, more like:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        ...
        <script>
            require([ 'dojo/on', 'dijit/registry' ], function (on, registry) {
                var dialogId = 'myDialog';

                on(document.getElementById('showButton'), 'click', function () {
                    var dialog = registry.byId(dialogId);
                    if (dialog) {
                        dialog.show();
                    }
                });
                on(document.getElementById('hideButton'), 'click', function () {
                    var dialog = registry.byId(dialogId);
                    if (dialog) {
                        dialog.hide();
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You don't really need to worry about tracking state, since calling `show` on an already visible dialog, or `hide` on a hidden one, has no effect.

Comment: Thank you for the education.  Still my problem is I cannot undim the screen, even as you state tracking state should not matter, assume no matter how many time dialog.show() is called?

Comment: What do you mean by "undim the screen"? Do you mean that even after a dialog has been dismissed, the background is dimmed? Or do you want to keep the screen from dimming even when a dialog is open?

Comment: mea culpa it is a repeat, yes should have answered yours first, policy matters of[link]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32289751/dojo-hide-not-clear?noredirect=1#comment52456991_32289751).  again excuse me